# arrary.includes ok in vscode but not tsc / tsify

Tags: typescript

using typescript I am trying to call array.includes. I have tsconfig set to say target = es6. In vscode there are no complaints, all works fine (It moaned big time till I changed target from es5 to es6)

But running through command line tsc (or tsify) it complains that `includes` is not valid

```
FuncLib.ts(15,23): error TS2339: Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[]'.
```

npm says I have typescript 2.9.1. Do I have to explicitly tell tsc (or tsifY) to read my tsconfig file?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this medium post](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/ecmascript-2016-es7-features-86903c5cab70) and this [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2340) the includes method is supported since ES7 (ES2016), try adding "ES2017" to your "lib" array in tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2017"],
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: i still dont get why vscode works and tsc doesnt. Adding es6 in vscode worked, but not tsc